# Can I send file from one project folder to an other project folder in C# web

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two projects in one solution. I know how to copy files from client to server file system. How can I copy files from client system using `admin project` and send into `client project` file system.

Comment: save your file in a folder and access it from both projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer you could 'Ctrl'-Drag the file to the name of the client project.
If you intend to keep the same code in both projects, I would suggest creating a class library as 3rd project, putting the file there, and adding a reference to this class library in both  the admin- and client-project.